# Save a set of data in columns in python

Tags: python, save, export, external

So I have the following code which is calculating the value of z varying x and y. It gives me 50 sets of values for z. The question is, how do I save it in a external file in 50 columns ?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 50, 51)
y = np.linspace(100, 150, 51)

for i in range(len(x)):
    z = y-x[i]

print z

with open("output_data.csv","w") as out_file:
    for i in range(len(x)):
        out_string=""
        out_string+=str(x[i])
        out_string += "," + str(z[i])
        out_string += "\n"
        out_file.write(out_string)
```

So far it only saves the first set of values

Comment: Try moving your first for loop immediately under the "with open" block.  Then move your second for loop immediately under your first for loop block (as a nested for loop).

Comment: yeah, tried it, but only gives me the values in the same column. Straight after the other. do you know how can I get it to save each set of z value in a different column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
out_string += ", " + str(z[i])
```

You need to change this to:

```
out_string += ", ".join((str(_z) for _z in z))
```